# read raw binary file in to bitset vector

Tags: c++, vector, boost, binary

Am I forced to read the file into a string and then convert the string to bitset?

I have  8192 bits stored in a file and I need to get the nth bit of every 256 bit set. My idea is to load all the bits into a `std::vector<std::bitset>` then use boost to `myvector | boost::adaptors::strided(64)` Is there a better way to do this? This was really easy to implement with python using the bitstring module but it was really slow. Trying to do it in C++ but running into all sorts of issues that I'm not familiar with.

Python code (this also switches the endianess of the byte) Here ch is 32, 32 byte arrays. The outer loops selects the large element and the inner loop reorders the byte.:

```
jrange = range(32)
irange = range(8) 
for j in jrange:
                for i in irange:
                    (BitArray([element[(7-i)+j*8] for element in ch])).tofile(outfile)
```

Comment: Do you want standard C++ or just Itanium ABI (MSVC/gcc/icc/etc.)?

Comment: With C++ you're already on the metal, dealing with bits. Why not just read `char`s and get the bits you want from there?

Comment: Do you have a binary file or is it a text file containing, for example, "1000010010010001..."?

Comment: What about [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)?

Comment: lorro: sadly I'm not even sure what your mentioning. rex: I wish to avoid reading into char because then to access the bits I would have to bit shift them into position or do some other logic. StephanLechner: It is a binary file. @user0042 I am very unfamiliar with C++ and even more unfamiliar with the boost library but I'll look into it, could be a great solution.