# how to combine binary nth bit of char vector

Tags: c++, vector, binary

Used to working in python and trying abstract how to access the binary elements of a single char vector item. The issue is that python was very slow and i'm translating this to c++. I have a binary file and i read the file into a `std::vector<char> buffer(1024)` and the data is organized so that there are 32 channels and each channel is 32 bytes(256 bits) long. A sample consists of 1 bit from each of the 32 channels. So there are 256 samples in a set. What is the best way to read combine the nth bit of each 32 byte channel into a sample? Python has a bitstring module, anything related to that in c++?

I'm not asking how to read raw binary data into a bitset vector. I am asking how to read the nth bit of a char vector.

Comment: Does this help http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read raw binary file in to bitset vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574899/read-raw-binary-file-in-to-bitset-vector)

Comment: Why read into std::vector<char>?

Comment: Is the data striped, like you want bit 0, bit 32, bit 64, etc combined to make the sample, then the same for the rest of the bits?

Comment: @lorro I was hoping to easily concatenate the different bytes into a new vector so it seemed like using vectors was the right answer. But I'm trying to drill down to the bit level so maybe there is a better method.

Comment: @RetiredNinja If each channel is 8 bits and i have 32 channels then one sample would be the combined bits:[0,8,16,24,32,...,248]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read the file into `std::vector<unsigned char>`, instead use `std::vector<std::bitset<32>>`.

First, read the file into an `std::vector` of `std::bitset`-s. Since it only have a constructor from an `unsigned long`, we have to do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::bitset<32>> batches;
std::ifstream fin(<path>, std::ios::binary);
uint32_t x;
while (fin >> x)
    batches.emplace_back(x);
```

Now, we have a vector that contains 256 batches of 32 bits each. Let's create the samples from them:

```
std::vector<std::bitset<256>> samples;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    std::bitset<256> sample;
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        sample[j] = batches[j][i];
    samples.push_back(sample);
}
```

Now your samples vector contains 32 samples of 256 bits each.

```
samples[i] // <-- Sample i
samples[i][j] // <-- Bit j in sample i
```

Comment: You're parsing uints instead of reading raw data... I suggest reading 4 chars & combinong them to uint.

Comment: @lorro, fixed fstream to binary mode.

Comment: Ah, scroll :) (looking at it on phone)

Comment: You'd want to use `fin.read(...)` to read binary data, not formatted input.